# TypeScript Array<T>.splice override

Tags: javascript, typescript

Within a class that derives from `Array<T>`, I have a `splice` override:

```
public splice(start?: number, deleteCount?: number, ...items: T[]): T[] {
    return super.splice(start, deleteCount, ...items);
}
```

Which compiles to...

```
SuperArray.prototype.splice = function (start, deleteCount) {
    var items = [];
    for (var _i = 2; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        items[_i - 2] = arguments[_i];
    }

    return _super.prototype.splice.apply(this, [start, deleteCount].concat(items));
};
```

This doesn't work at all. It completely breaks splice! Is there something wrong with the way it compiles this `.apply(this, [start, deleteCount].concat(items))` and how do I fix it?

What is happened with splice? Why it is broken?

```
array.splice(0); // array unaffected
```

Comment: What is happened with `splice`? Why it is broken?

Comment: @timocov see update

Comment: Behavior is the same
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20SuperArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20splice(start%3F%3A%20number%2C%20deleteCount%3F%3A%20number%2C%20...items%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super.splice(start%2C%20deleteCount%2C%20...items)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20s%20%3D%20new%20SuperArray(1%2C%202%2C%203)%3B%0D%0As.splice(0)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(s)%3B%0D%0Alet%20v%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0D%0Av.splice(0)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(v)%3B

Comment: Your "super splice" frankly just wouldn't work as defined, it's totally ambiguous. Suppose you had a super array of numbers, how exactly is that function supposed to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason this happens is that `deleteCount` is `undefined`, and if you try this:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
a.splice(0, undefined); // []
console.log(a); /// [1, 2, 3]
```

Exactly the same thing.
To get over this, you'll need to build the arguments array yourself, something like this:

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    public splice(start?: number, deleteCount?: number, ...items: T[]): T[] {
        if (start == undefined) {
            start = 0; // not sure here, but you wanted it to be optional
        }

        if (deleteCount == undefined) {
            deleteCount = this.length - start; // the default
        }

        const args = ([start, deleteCount] as any[]).concat(items);
        return super.splice.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Or something like:

```
public splice(start?: number, deleteCount?: number, ...items: T[]): T[] {
    if (deleteCount != undefined) {
        return super.splice(start, deleteCount, ...items);
    } else {
        return super.splice(start, ...items);
    }
}
```

But I haven't tested this one.